# if-emoji lookup table with Vue

Tags: vue.js, emoji

I'm using the npm module [`if-emoji`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/if-emoji) to detect whether a user can view emojis or not. There is a similar tool in Modernizr.

If the user can't view emojis, I'm displaying an image of the emoji instead. So my Vue HTML looks like this:

```html
<h2 v-if="this.emojis"></h2>
<h2 v-if="!this.emojis"><img src="https://example.com/emoji.png">/h2>
```

Does this still download the image for users who can view emojis, therefore using bandwidth unecessarily?

And is there a more efficient way of doing this, so that I don't need to go and add `v-if` every time I use an emoji? Can there be some sort of lookup table, if there's an emoji and `!this.emojis`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this also by creating your own vue.component

```
<emojiorimage usesmily="false" smily="" imgpath="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdqVi.png"></emojiorimage>
```

that capsulates the decision if image or smily inside itself.

```js
  var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: function(){
      return {
        extendedCost: 0,
      }
    },
    components: { "emojiorimage" : {
      template : `
        <h2>
          usesmily is {{usesmily}}<br/>
          <div v-if="usesmily === 'true'">{{ smily }}</div>
          <div v-else><img :scr="imgpath" width="50" height="50" :alt="imgpath" /></div>
        </h2>`,
      props: ["usesmily", "smily", "imgpath"],
    }}
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
   <h1>Emoji or Image</h1>
 
  <emojiorimage
    usesmily="false"
    smily=""
    imgpath="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdqVi.png"
  ></emojiorimage>
 
  <emojiorimage
    usesmily="true"
    smily=""
    imgpath="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdqVi.png"
  ></emojiorimage>
</div>
```

You can then feed it the isemoji from your npm package that you query once and store somewhere.

---

### For seperate vue files it would look kind of like this:

[image: Project]

### `emojiorimage.vue`

```
<template>
  <h2>    
    <div v-if="usesmily === 'true'">{{ smily }}</div>
    <div v-else><img :scr="imgpath" width="50" height="50" 
        :alt="imgpath" /></div>
  </h2>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["usesmily", "smily", "imgpath"],
};
</script>
```

### `App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Emoji or Image</h1>

    <emojiorimage
      usesmily="false"
      smily=""
      imgpath="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdqVi.png"
    />

    <emojiorimage
      usesmily="true"
      smily=""
      imgpath="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdqVi.png"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import emojiorimage from "./components/emojiorimage.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    emojiorimage,
  },
};
</script>
```

### `index.html`

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

### `index.js`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: "<App/>",
  components: { App }
});
```

to get:

[image: Image of preview of page]

Learning resources:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: A really great idea, thank you! I think I've improved upon it slightly by not having to specify the url as a prop, and so it auto sizes the emoji (using an npm module called ``fitty`` / image to match surrounding text. I will post an answer with my update. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<h2 v-if="true"></h2>
<h2 v-else><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" width=15 height=15></h2>

<h2 v-if="false"></h2>
<h2 v-else><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" width=15 height=15></h2>
```

The `v-if` part only is part of the sourcecode if the statement is true - else the else statement is in instead. If the img tag is not part of the loaded source the image wont be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h2 v-if="emojis"></h2>
<h2 v-else><img src="https://example.com/emoji.png"></h2>
```

Is probably the only way to improve your code as [@Patrick Artner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner) pointed out.

*You do not need `this.` in the template*

To the question if the image is loaded if it is not shown the simple answer is no. Vue only renders `v-ifs` when they are needed and does not render it - the image is loaded only if `!emojis`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @PatrickArtner who posted the idea of using a Vue component to render the emoji / image. Here is my final solution, which resizes the emoji / image to fit the surrounding text — it uses [`fitty`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fitty) to resize the emojis, and sets the images to `height:1em;`.

`Emoji.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div class="emojiContainer">
    <span id="fittyEmoji" v-if="emojis">{{ insert }}</span>
    <img v-if="!emojis" :src="insert" class="emojiImage">
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .emojiContainer {
    display: inline;
  }
  .emojiImage {
    height:1em;
  }
</style>

<script src="fitty.min.js"></script>

<script>

import fitty from 'fitty';
import ifEmoji from 'if-emoji'

export default {
  name: 'Emoji',
  props: ['name'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      insert: "",
      emojis: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    insertEmoji(){
      var names = ['frog', 'fire']
      var emojis = ['','']
      var urls = ['https://example.com/frog.png',
                  'https://example.com/fire.png']
      if (this.emojis) {
        this.insert = emojis[names.indexOf(this.name)];
      } else {
        this.insert = urls[names.indexOf(this.name)];
      }
      fitty('#fittyEmoji')
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    if (ifEmoji('')) {
      this.emojis = true;
    } else {
      this.emojis = false;
    }
    this.insertEmoji();
  }
}
</script>
```

Then in your parent components you can just insert like this:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1><Emoji name='frog'/> Frog Facts</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum <Emoji name='fire'/><p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Emoji from '@/components/Emoji.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Emoji,
  },
};
</script>
```